# Spring kafka performance vs native kafka api

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am a developer who using Spring Kafka for producing/consuming, now I have a question about the performance. What is the performance difference between Spring Kafka VS native Kafka API? Is there any performance drop using Spring Kafka comparing with native Kafka API?
Anyone has tried that performance before and know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: This question is very general.. It possibly belongs on [programmers.se].

Comment: @Dev-iL this question is a poor fit for Software Engineering - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see https://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

You should not see any significant performance differences.